# Equivalent in Autofac of TryAddEnumerable from default .net DI

Tags: autofac

I am having a hard time finding the answer to my question so I am gonna put it like that.

This in .net 7 :
`services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped\<CircuitHandler, MyCustomCircuit\>());`

does the equivalent in Autofac is :
`builder.RegisterType\<MyCustomCircuit\>().As\<CircuitHandler\>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope();`

Comment: Definitely, this answer is not what I proposed up there as I get this exception : 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' in Autofac.dll.  Which I don't when I use the default .net DI

Comment: Im not really familiar with .net implementation of IoC, but i'm quite sure it does not support named scopes. But Autofac does and your registration "InstancePerMachingLifetimeScope()" is doing exactly that. https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html
"You will get an exception if you try to resolve a per-matching-lifetime-scope 
component when there’s no correctly named lifetime scope." 
Perhaps you should first try using InstancePerLifetimeScope() instead.

Comment: Hi, by "named scopes" are you talking about "MyCustomCircuit". If so, this is a class implementing this abstract class "CircuitHandler".  So, in reality what it does, it's registering MyCustomCircuit, and keeping other implementation of "CircuitHandler" that are not of the type "MyCustomCircuit".